Security Concerns of using unrestricted js with a payment Webview
So I am using webview_flutter to make a Webview to get user payments.
I was curious about this line of code
..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
The payment webview does not open without this line. I was wondering about the security concerns about this, since I am dealing with sensitive information such as payment info.
I found this blog and answered some questions.
I would like some more insight or resources, I would also like some references to blogs or articles as well if possible.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
